# Invite different collaborators to different subfolders of a repository

Tags: git, github

I have bought a `personal user account` of github.

For example, I have created a repository `repo`, and it has two subfolders: `app1`, `app2`.

Does anyone know if it is possible to invite `collaborator1` for the `app1` subfolder, and invite `collaborator2` for the `app2` subfolder.

If this is impossible with `personal user account`, does `organisation account` permit this?

PS: I have some other files (eg, `test.sh`) under `repo` that use both `app1` and `app2`, so if I create two separate repositories for `app1` and `app2` (rather than an entire `repo`), I will not be able to put those test files in git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good case for git submodules.

As lest mentioned, you'll first need to create separate repositories for `app1` and `app2`. These are entirely independent and don't know about each other, you therefore can have separate permissions.

You can then add `app1` and `app2` as submodules, in the `repo` repository.

In `repo` repository, remove the app1 and app2 directories (after creating their respective repos, of course) and run:

```
git submodule add git@github.com/username/app1
git submodule add git@github.com/username/app2
```

These two repositories will be added as directories in the root of the `repo` repository and will be tracked in the newly created `.gitmodules` file. The tests scripts will not have to be changed as they will just see the directories as normal.

Users can checkout `app1` and `app2` as independent repositories, but you can also get all the code with the following:

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com/username/repo
```

Or if you already have `repo` cloned you can update the submodules using:

```
git submodule update --init
```

For more information, consult the [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to define permissions for folders inside a single repository, not even with an organization account. I would suggest splitting your repository into separate repositories to set up custom permissions for each of them.